# Kernel crash when using NIntegrate with Throw/Catch

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs

**Bug fixed in 10.2.0**

---

My code is:

```
Catch[
 NIntegrate[
  1, {x, y} \[Element] Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}], 
  Method -> "MonteCarlo", EvaluationMonitor :> Throw[{x, y}]
 ]
]
```

After I input it, a window (shown below) is returned:

[image: the memory could not be "written"]

My system is Windows 7, 32 bit.

Comment: The kernel shouldn't crash. I've let the appropriate developers know and they will be looking into it. Not sure what the input is intended to do, perhaps something like `Reap[NIntegrate[
  1, {x, y} \[Element] Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}], 
  Method -> "MonteCarlo", EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]]]` may work?

Comment: @ilian Nice to meet you-WRI engineer.Reap-Sow works normally. But I only want the first random point in this region.

Comment: @ilian I can't translate the Chinese sentence in the window into English.

Comment: I can't translate it either, but I think it is the standard Windows "memory could not be written" crash dialog, e.g. http://i.stack.imgur.com/U4QK1.jpg

The first point sown would be `Reap[NIntegrate[...]][[2, 1, 1]]`. In other threads, there are also several nice ways to generate random points in a region.

Comment: @ilian Yes,your guess is true,since I find that the meaning of sentences of two windows matches.

Comment: @ilian I need a function to generate random points in arbitary region (ranged from 0 dimension to 3 dimension) .

Comment: This functionality is coming soon, but for the time being perhaps try `NIntegrate\`RandomRegion[reg, n]` to generate `n` random points.

Comment: @ilian I wonder why mathematica don't have a function to calculate the differential-Grobner basis,since I find it useful for a large number of problem.And I notice that  DSolve in  mathematica for PDE is relatively weaker than maple.I suggest that WRI should strength the functionality in this field in next editions.

Comment: @ilian That's a surprising exciting information for me.Thank you.

Comment: @ilian It failed when the region is Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}].In other words, NIntegrate`RandomRegionTriangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}], 1] `doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23771/discussion-between-ilian-and-watesoyan).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now fixed in version 10.2.

```
In[1]:= Catch[NIntegrate[                                                       
      1, {x, y} \[Element] Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}],              
      Method -> "MonteCarlo", EvaluationMonitor :> Throw[{x, y}]]]          

Out[1]= {0.615426, 0.793388}
```

There is also [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html):

```
In[2]:= RandomPoint[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}]]                         

Out[2]= {1.44991, 0.822952}
```